# In Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, what are the unions $\cup \emptyset$ and $\cup \{\emptyset\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand the basic premise of the Unions Axiom, i.e. that it takes 'the elements of the elements' and 'unpacks' the set by $1$ level (e.g. $\{\{a\},\{\{b\},c\}\} \to \{a, \{b\}, c\}$), but I can't find any info on what it does to sets like $\emptyset$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ - and I am afraid to assume as I often mix up the numbers of $\{\}$'s needed! Can anyone share any insights here?

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting mathematics on this website.

Comment: Correct, you have to unpack 'the elements of the elements': what are the elements of $\emptyset$ ? And what are the elements of $\{ \emptyset \}$ ?

Comment: Hint: Definition: ∪x = { y | ∃b∈X(y∈b)}

Answer (score 1):

- $\cup \emptyset=\emptyset$ is the empty set itself. If we explicitly write the axiom of union:
  $$\forall A \, \exists B \, \forall c \ (c \in B \iff (c\in D \ \land D\in A ) )  $$
  we can see that, if $A=\emptyset$, than it does not exist an element $D \in A$, so the conjunction $(c\in D \ \land D\in A)$ does not hold for any $c$, thus there is no $c$ in the union set $B$.
- $\cup \{\emptyset\}=\emptyset$ because as before, if $A=\{\emptyset \}$, the conjuction $(c\in D \ \land D\in A)$ does not hold for any $c$, because the only $D\in A$ is the empty set, thus there exist no $c$ inside this $D$. Thus, also in this case $B=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

The Axiom of Union states that, for any set $S$, there is a set $U$ such that $x\in U$ if and only if $x\in A$ for some $A\in S$.

For the $\emptyset$ case, $S=\emptyset$, there is no $A\in S$ and thus no $x\in A$, the answer is $\emptyset$.

For the $\{\emptyset\}$ case, $S=\{\emptyset\}$, there is only one $A=\emptyset\in S$ and thus no $x\in A$, the answer is still $\emptyset$.